# Get 2nd occurence of between a pattern

Tags: regex

given

```
System Volume Information|28-May-15 3:16:25 AM|06-Aug-15 9:25:59 AM|5|
```

I need to get 2nd date of between `| |` occurrence which is `|06-Aug-15 9:25:59 AM|` . I am able to get the first and the last |5| with the regex below:

```
(?<=\|)(.*?)(?=\|) //First Date
(?<=\|)(.?)(?=\|) //Last occurrence|5|
```

Regex:
https://regex101.com/r/aB1sC2/2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this regex:

```
(?:[^|]+\|){2}([^|]+)
```

And grab captured group #1

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/aB1sC2/3)